# Indented namespacing with python

Tags: python, types, namespaces

I have a config file with loads of paths and I want to organize them in a way. So I decided using `types.SimpleNamespace` to do that like:

```
paths = SimpleNamespace()
paths.base = '...'
paths.dataset.encoded = '...'
```

and I got:

```
AttributeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'dataset'
```

I tried to define `paths.dataset` even though I didn't need it yet it didn't work:

```
paths = SimpleNamespace()
paths.base = '...'
paths.dataset = '...'
paths.dataset.encoded = '...'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoded'
```

I also tried this:

```
_ = {
    'base': '...',
    'dataset': {
        'encoded': '...',
    }
}
paths = SimpleNamespace(**_)
```

and here is the result:

```
>>> paths.dataset.encoded  # Error
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encoded'
>>> paths.dataset['encoded']  # works
'...'
```

This means that SimpleNamespace only works for one layer namespacing, right?

Is there another solution to this? I mean a solution other than using SimpleNamespace for every layer like this:

```
dataset = SimpleNamespace()
dataset.encoded = '...'

paths = SimpleNamespace()
paths.base = '???'
paths.dataset = dataset

>>> paths.base
'???'
>>> paths.dataset.encoded
'...'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you expect a specific shape of your configuration, why not define it as actual classes instead of arbitrarily extendable namespaces?

Comment: @mistermiyagi well I tried it but I failed due to my little knowledge of classes. Would you please demonstrate an example? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
def create_namespace(dictionary: dict):
    """Create a namespace of given dictionary

    the difference between create_namespace and python's types.SimpleNamespace
    is that the former will create name space recursively, but the later will
    create the namespace in one layer indentation. See the examples to see the
    difference.

    Parameters
    ----------
    dictionary : dict
        A dict to be converted to a namespace object

    Returns
    -------
    types.SimpleNamespace
        A combination of SimpleNamespaces that will have an multilayer
        namespace

    Examples
    --------
    >>> dictionary = {
    ...     'layer1_a': '1a',
    ...     'layer1_b': {
    ...         'layer2_a': '2a',
    ...     },
    ... }

    >>> # types.SimpleNamespace
    >>> simple = SimpleNamespace(**dictionary)
    >>> simple.layer1_a
    '1a'
    >>> simple.layer1_b.layer2_a
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'layer2_a'
    # because layer1_b is still a dictionary

    >>> # create_namespace
    >>> complex = create_namespace(dictionary)
    >>> complex.layer1_a
    '1a'
    >>> complex.layer1_a.layer2_a
    '2a'
    """
    space = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = create_namespace(value)
        space[key] = value
    return SimpleNamespace(**space)
```

but I think there is a better way that I'm not seeing. I appreciate any comments on this.